# how to invoke connection between pushed state and form input

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a form and i use v-model for that to connect it to computed , and computed use get and set with object in VueX ,
when form is submitted that object will pushed into main array , the problem is that , even after push the connection between form input and pushed object in array will not disconnect and when new form submited the old will change ,

this is computed that v-modeled whith text input

```js
  computed: {
    name: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.item.name
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('mut_up_name', value)
      },
    },
```

and this is vuex mutations

```js
    export const mutations = {
  mut_up_name(state,v){
    state.item.name=v
  },
```

and this code push obj to main array

```js
  add_item(state) {
        let a={...state.item}
        state.items.push(a)
        
      },
```

how can i envoke connection between pushed state & input

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid changing the state directly inside of vuex actions and if you would like to change the value of the input, use @input instead and dispatch your actions from there. If you would like mutate multiple actions, then you can take a look from my approach:

Template:

```
<template>
  <some-input-component :value="name" @input="inputHandler($event)"/>
</template>
```

Script:

```
computed: {
  name() {
    return this.$store.state.item.name;
  },
},
methods: {
  inputHandler(e) {
    this.$store.dispatch('add_item', e);
  },
},
```

in the vuex:

```
state: {
  item: {
    name: '',
  },
  someArray: [],
},
actions: {
  add_item: ({ commit }, e) => {
    commit('mutate_name', e);
    commit('push_item', e);
  }
},
mutations: {
  mutate_name: (state, value) => {
    state.item.name = value;
  },
  push_item: (state, obj) => {
    state.someArray.push(obj);
  },
},
```